Significant Page Creation Time Difference Between Xamarin.Forms and .NET MAUI
I have observed a significant difference in page creation times between Xamarin.Forms and .NET MAUI when repeatedly instantiating the same page.
Why does .NET MAUI have a constant page creation time for repeated instantiations while Xamarin.Forms shows significantly reduced times for subsequent instantiations? Is there a way to achieve similar performance optimizations in .NET MAUI as seen in Xamarin.Forms?
I created a performance test page with a large number of UI elements in both a Xamarin.Forms and a .NET MAUI application. I then measured the time it takes to instantiate the page using the following code:
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var newPage = new PerformanceTestPage();
Debug.WriteLine("Page creation: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Test Results
Xamarin.Forms (First Button Click): Page Creation Time: 100-110 ms
.NET MAUI (First Button Click): Page Creation Time: 80-90 ms
Xamarin.Forms (Subsequent Button Clicks): Page Creation Time: 1-2 ms
.NET MAUI (Subsequent Button Clicks): Page Creation Time: 80+ ms

You can refer to this blog: .NET 8 Performance Improvements in .NET MAUI.
